# How to run script for all files in a folder/directry

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have successful written a script to search for something within a file using :

`open(r"C:\file.txt)` and `re.search` function and all works fine.

Is there a way to do the search function with all files within a folder? Because currently, I have to manually change the file name of my script by  `open(r"C:\file.txt),`open(r"C:\file1.txt)`,`open(r"C:\file2.txt)`, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: check out `os.listdir` or `os.walk` function

Comment: You can execute a `grep` command from python too, Im sure it will be better in performance.

Comment: @Wonka: did you try it? The overhead of launching a new process may be more important than the overhead of the Python interpretor...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk` to check all the files, as the following:

```
import os
for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as f:
            #your code goes here
```

**Explanation**:

`os.walk` returns `tuple` of `(root path, dir names, file names)` in the `folder`, so you can `iterate` through `filenames` and open each file by using `os.path.join(root, filename)` which basically joins the root path with the file name so you can open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os.listdir(path) function:

```
import os

path = '/Users/ricardomartinez/repos/Salary-API'

# List for all files in a given PATH
file_list = os.listdir(path)

# If you want to filter by file type
file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.py']


# Both cases yo can iterate over the list and apply the operations
# that you have

for file in file_list:
    print(file)
    #Operations that you want to do over files
```

Comment: "# If you want to filter by file type" : this actually filters on the two last letters of the file name - and will break if you have a file named say "whooppy" -, not on "file type". If you want to filter on file extension (which is still not "file type"), you want to use `os.path.splitext()` and test on the second element of the result.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers As you have suggested,  i have edited my answer, and also forgive my english, i want to say file extension, knowing that not always the file extension represent the file type, thanks a lot to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a beginner, I'll give you a simple solution and walk through it.

Import the os module, and use the os.listdir function to create a list of everything in the directory. Then, iterate through the files using a for loop.

Example:

```
# Importing the os module
import os

# Give the directory you wish to iterate through
my_dir = <your directory -  i.e. "C:\Users\bleh\Desktop\files">

# Using os.listdir to create a list of all of the files in dir
dir_list = os.listdir(my_dir)

# Use the for loop to iterate through the list you just created, and open the files
for f in dir_list:
    # Whatever you want to do to all of the files
```

If you need help on the concepts, refer to the following:

for looops in p3: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_for_loop.php

os function Library (this has some cool stuff in it): https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Good luck!